# Rerender part of react-native list item

Tags: listview, react-native

I have a list view that is currently displaying data from a data source. In my list items, there is an icon. I would like that icon to change based on application state. When this.state.deleteMode = true, I need the icon to be a minus sign. When its false, it needs to be a chevron. this.state.deleteMode is toggled via a button.

I am using https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-elements#lists in conjunction with the standard React-Native list view.

The problem I am having is that I am not sure how to force my listview to update only the icon. Everything else in the list items will stay the same. Only the icon needs to change. Is there a way to rerender the icon without forcing the entire list item to rerender? I have an image in my list items and when it rerenders the entire list item there is a brief flash when the image is redrawn. I would like to avoid that if possible

Answer (score 0):

I just tried a similar situation on a similar app on Android and my images aren't reloaded when I update a list item props. It could be something with how you're loading your rows. Here's some of my code of my `List` component, which receives the items as an array from a top "scene" which handles the state.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { ds: null };
}

static propTypes = {
    deleting:   React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    onSelect:   React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    collection: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.id !== r2.id });
    this.setState({ ds: ds.cloneWithRows(props.collection) });
}

renderRow(item, section, index, highlight) {
    return (
        <ListItem deleting={this.props.deleting} onSelect={this.props.onSelect} index={index} model={item}/>
    );
}

render() {
    if(!this.state.ds){
        return (
            <View/>
        );
    }

    if(this.state.ds.getRowCount() === 0){
        return (
            <View/>
        );
    }

    return (
        <ListView dataSource={ this.state.ds } renderRow={ this.renderRow.bind(this) }/>
    );
}
```

`ListItem` is a simple without anything in particular.

Comment: hmm. mine dont reload every time it seems. They reload maybe every 3rd time or so i toggle my delete state. They are coming from a server though, not sure if yours are or not

Comment: Yes, mine are also JPEG's being loaded server side. Weird.